# FFMPEG output from motion detection is gray

Tags: video, ffmpeg, playback, editing

I have taken footage I recorded and wanted to use FFmpeg to cut out still frames of the file, however, I just get a file of the same size, but it is all grayed out.

Command Used:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.0003),setpts=N/(30*TB)" output.mp4\
```

Output:
[image]

This is gameplay of MTG Arena btw

When I run this in FFplay, however, it looks normal.

Still, however, no cuts or removal happen, as it is still the same length video.

At this point I have two questions.

1) How do I cut frames with no motion in FFmpeg

2) Why does this footage appear gray.

My video player is MPC-HC

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems that the original video is a bit broken. Or, it has too few keyframes.

Try to recode the video with ffmpeg first, perhaps adding a keyframe often. Then try again.